# Using Bootstrap 4 media queries in css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, postcss

I'm importing bootstrap with `postcssEasyImport` from `./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css` and I was wondering how to use media query variables like `@screen-md-min` or if that is only available in scss.

Answer (score 0):

@screen-md-min is a mixin, not a variable. Variables in SASS are prefixed with $, i.e. $colorVar, whereas mixins are prefixed with @.
 Mixins do not work in CSS, you need a preprocessor (SASS, LESS etc.) for that.

However, you can still use media queries in CSS, but you have to type them out with specific px widths, meaning that

```
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) {

}
```

in SASS would be

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {

}
```

in CSS.
As for variables in CSS, I suggest reading this article on CSS-Tricks: https://css-tricks.com/difference-between-types-of-css-variables/

Hope this helps.